Parse number with regexp
I have a text block as a paragraph that starts from some number as a string. There could be simple numbers or dotted ones. I have the next paragraph numbers:
1) sovereign control will prevail

1.1. These are the Rules

5.47.1 "Пункт зупинки тролейбуса".

I use the next regexp expression to find the number.
([0-9.,\\-\\s]+)\\b")

Now, I got the new  number format
source text
 5.24.1 і 5.24.2 "Зміна напрямку руху на дорозі з розділювальною смугою"

I need to get the number 5.24.1_ 5.24.2
How can regex expression be written to use one all scenario?

Why do you have a whitespace and hyphen in the pattern? Shouldn't it be just \d+(?:\.\d+)+? See https://regex101.com/r/hkse0N/1

the text block number may contain ).  The simplest expression does not find it
5) якщо будинок підлягає капітальному ремонту з 


Aha, so you want to match various styles of these bullet points. Still, I'd rather use a more precise pattern to only search for these entities at the start of the string. Try String regex = "\\G(?:\\s*(?:\\sі\\s+)?)(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)+|\\d+\\))";, see the regex demo

Excelent. Unfortunattely I found addidtional case
а)  driver licance

Is it possible to add this to last expression ?

See https://regex101.com/r/hkse0N/3, https://regex101.com/r/hkse0N/3/codegen?language=java

I suggest matching any of the following patterns at the start of string only:

alphanumeric characters followed with a ) char
dot-separated digit sequences
dot-separated digit sequences separated with conjunctions (you may then extend this with more conjunctions as need be).

The regex will look like
String regex = "(?U)\\G\\s*(?:\\sі\\s+)?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)+|\\w+\\))";

See the regex demo.
Details:

(?U) - Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS inline flag option (I see you may have Cyrillic letters in the expected matches, so it is required for the \w to match them)
\G - either start of string or the end of the previous match (so we only allow to match consecutive matches from the start of the string)
\s* - zero or more whitespaces
(?:\sі\s+)? - an optional sequence of a whitespace, і and then one or more whitespaces
(\d+(?:\.\d+)+|\w+\)) - Group 1: either

\d+(?:\.\d+)+ - one or more digits and then one or more sequences of a . + one or more digits
| - or
\w+\) - one or more alphanumeric chars and then a ) char.



See the Java testing code online:
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String regex = "(?U)\\G\\s*(?:\\sі\\s+)?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)+|\\w+\\))";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        List<String> strs = Arrays.asList(
            "а) driver licance",
            "1) sovereign control will prevail",
            "1.1. These are the Rules",
            "5.47.1 \"Пункт зупинки тролейбуса\".",
            "5.24.1 і 5.24.2 \"Зміна напрямку руху на дорозі з розділювальною смугою\"");
        for (String str : strs) {
            System.out.println("Input: \"" + str + "\"");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
            while (matcher.find()){
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
            } 
            System.out.println("-- END OF STRING PROCESSING --");
        }
    }
}

Output:
Input: "а) driver licance"
а)
-- END OF STRING PROCESSING --
Input: "1) sovereign control will prevail"
1)
-- END OF STRING PROCESSING --
Input: "1.1. These are the Rules"
1.1
-- END OF STRING PROCESSING --
Input: "5.47.1 "Пункт зупинки тролейбуса"."
5.47.1
-- END OF STRING PROCESSING --
Input: "5.24.1 і 5.24.2 "Зміна напрямку руху на дорозі з розділювальною смугою""
5.24.1
5.24.2
-- END OF STRING PROCESSING --


excellent. Thank you

Sometimes, the greater complexity of a code is compensated by a greater ductility and velocity, I know it is not what you are asking for, but...
List<String> getNumbers( String input ) {
   boolean findNumber = true;
   String aux[] = input.split( "" );
   String aux2 = "";
   List<String> out = new ArrayList<>();
   for( int k = 0; k < aux.length; k ++ ) {
      if( findNumber ) {
         if( aux[ k ].matches( "[0-9]" ) ) {
            aux2 += aux[ k ];
            findNumber = false;
         }
      }
      else {
         if( aux[ k ].matches( "[0-9]" )
                 || aux[ k ].matches( "\\." ) ) {
            aux2 += aux[ k ];
         }
         else {
            out.add( aux2 );
            aux2 = "";
            findNumber = true;
         }
      }
   }
   return out;
}


splitting each character as a String and then using regular expression on each (to just check range 0-9) is certainly not the best practice.... if you need to work with each char, then use  char (much faster than using regular expression)

( if you need regular expression, find the two numbers and concatenate these )

Master, I learn from you every day, and I will continue to do so, I know that my solutions are almost always suboptimal, I just raise them as a base idea, thanks for your comments.

that is why I also comment... my initial steps for above code: instead of split() use toCharArray() to get a char[] ¹ ; instead of matches("[0-9]") maybe if ('0' <= chars[k] && chars[k] <= '9') (eventually using a temporary char ch = chars[k]) --- ¹ note that char is not able to represent all Unicode characters; it is recommended to use code points (e.g. using codePoints() from String) - unfortunately the String class does not have the best support for code points (to use with usual for loops)

if ('0' <= chars[k] && chars[k] <= '9') I had not thought of it, so simple and so effective!!!!.
